# Square integrable functions on T

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

$L^2(\mathbb{T})$ is the set of square integrable functions on the unit circle. This is also a hilbert space over the complex field. Now objects in this vector space are functions, but what is their domain and range? Are they only defined on the unit circle?

Also, $\{e^{inx}: n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is an orthonormal basis. How can I show that this is a maximal orthonormal basis?

Thanks.

Comment: Any book on Fourier series has  a  proof of  the fact that $(e^{inx})$ is  a basis.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know its an orthanormal set but I dont know how to show it is a maximal orthanormal set. I know I can use Weierstrass to show the set is dense in the space of continuous functions, but L^2(T) contains discontinuous functions too...

Comment: There is another basic result which says the continuous functions are dense in $L^{2}(T)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh. Do you know where I can find that result? I know very little about measure theory. Also, are the functions in L^2(T) only defined on the unit circle, or the whole complex plane?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459524/showing-einx-is-an-orthonormal-basis-in-l2-pi-pi).

Comment: $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ does not consist of functions. An element $f$ of this space is an equivalence class of Lebesgue measurable functions on $\mathbb{T}$ that are equal a.e. to one another. They are not defined pointwise.