# How to prove on the vector space of continuous functions from $[−π, π]$ to $\mathbb{C}$ sets are closed, bounded and and not compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Please, help me:

Let $X = C([−\pi, \pi])$ be the vector space of continuous functions from $[−π, π]$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Consider $\| f \|_2= \left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}$ as the $L^2$-norm and $T$ as the associated norm topology. Let $e_k: [−\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined as $e_k(x) = \displaystyle\frac{e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, for $k ∈ \mathbb{Z}$.
Show that the set $\{e_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is closed and bounded but not compact.
Show that the unit sphere $\{x \in X , \|x\|_2 = 1\}$ is closed and bounded but not compact.

My idea:
Let $(e_{k_i})$ be a sequence in $\{e_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ that converges uniformly to a function $f$ on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$. We need to demonstrate that $f$ also belongs to $\{e_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Uniform convergence means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an index $N$ such that for all $i \geq N$, we have $|e_{k_i}(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x$ in $[-π, π]$ and for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the Fourier coefficients of $f$, denoted as $c_k$. We can express $f$ as a Fourier series:

$$f(x) = \sum_k c_k e_k(x)$$

Since $(e_k)_k$ forms an orthonormal basis, we can compute the Fourier coefficients of $f$ as:

$$c_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e_k(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Now, let's examine the Fourier coefficients of the sequence $(e_{k_i})_i$:

$$c_{k_i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e_{k_i}(x) e_k(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Since the sequence $(e_{k_i})_i$ converges uniformly to $f$, we can interchange the limit and the integral, leading to:

$$\lim_{i \to \infty} c_{k_i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \lim_{i \to \infty} e_{k_i}(x) e_k(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Now, we need to show that $\lim_{i \to \infty} e_{k_i}(x) e_k(x) = \delta_k$, the Kronecker delta function, which is $1$ if $k = k_i$ and $0$ otherwise. This implies that the Fourier coefficients of $f$ coincide with those of the sequence $(e_{k_i})_i$.

To prove this point, we can calculate the integral:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e_{k_i}(x) e_k(x) dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(kᵢ-k)x} \mathrm{d}x$$

Since $e^{i(k_i-k)x}$ is periodic with period $2π$, the integral over $[-\pi, \pi]$ will give us $2π$ multiplied by the Kronecker delta:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e_{k_i}(x) e_k(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(k_i-k)x} \mathrm{d}x = \delta_k k_i 2π$$

Hence, we have:

$$\lim_{i \to \infty} c_{k_i} = \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \lim_{i \to \infty} e_{k_i}(x) e_k(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \delta_k k_i 2π \mathrm{d}x = δ_k k_i$$

This shows that the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are identical to those of the sequence $(e_{k_i})$. Therefore, $f$ can also be expressed as a Fourier series using the coefficients $c_{k_i}$, and since the $e_k$ functions form an orthonormal system, $f$ belongs to the set $\{e_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Hence, the set $\{e_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is closed in the norm topology of $X$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format the math in your question. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick reference.

Comment: I reformatted everything, but if you still want to re-delete everything you can do so. You can right-click on MathJax expressions and go "Show Math As > TeX Commands" to see how I wrote them.

Comment: I tried to stay true to what you wrote. I would advise not using the letter $i$ for indexation since $i$ the imaginary unit is already present.

Comment: @Bruno B  thanks very much.....

Comment: The topology $T$ associated with the $L^2$ norm is not the topology associated with uniform convergence

Comment: @leslietownes  But i wanna show if  we consider a sequence (eₖᵢ) ⊆ {eₖ: k ∈ Z} that converges to a limit point f in X with respect to the norm L^2, f also belongs to the set {eₖ: k ∈ Z}.

Comment: prove that these functions are orthonormal https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459524/showing-einx-is-an-orthonormal-basis-in-l2-pi-pi